# is there a way to change the color of seaborn violin_plot

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

Following is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

The following line gives me a normal violin plot of species vs sepal_length:

```
sns.violinplot(x = df['species'], y = df['sepal_length'])
```

The output looks as such

[image: species vs sepal_length]

Now, I need to change the color of each plot, that's where I'm stuck
Is there a way to do it by staying in seaborn violin_plot and not going into matplotlib or anything?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that is to use a simple parameter of seaborn's violin_plot called `pallete`.

Following is the code for that:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.violinplot(x = df['species'], y = df['sepal_length'], palette = ['green', 'blue', 'yellow'])
```

and BAM ! it's done.